# Memory error in a for loop with only two iterations

Tags: python, for-loop, out-of-memory

I am experiencing an issue with my computer memory when running a for loop with (only) 2 iterations. The point I have a problem to understand is that it works fine when I run my script with only 1 iteration (so not really a for loop anymore). I was not expecting a memory error because all my variables are overwritten during the 2nd iteration.. So the memory shouldn't be used more, but I am obviously missing something.

To give you a bit more context, I am analyzing data coming from 2 different experimental sessions, each of them designated with a key:

(*Parameters is a class I created*)

```
keys = ['20191125.01.1', '20191125.01.2']
n_ses = len(keys)
for ses, key in enumerate(keys):
    # LOAD PARAMETERS
    p = Parameters(key, preproc='rt')
    ...
```

Then I load/save data and call some functions. It would be too long to explicit everything here but I guess that the points which might be problematic are:

- that I am doing parallel processing using [joblib.Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html) in one function, with `n_jobs=4`,
- and that I plot data with [matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) at some point (but I don't use `show()` and apply `clf()` method at the end systematically)

I would be very grateful if someone could give me even a clue about why the 1st iteration of the above loop works without a problem when the 2nd one causes a memory error.

Comment: You mention you are not expecting to run out of memory because "your variables are overwritten".  So, are you saying that you are doing a calculation that uses a very large amount of memory, but you _think_ you are freeing it correctly so it shouldnt be a problem?  If that's the case, this question is probably a question about how to properly make sure Python can reclaim memory. If that's not it, then perhaps you have something that is going much broader than you expect. Maybe you are running more parallel than you think or similar. You might do some tests to confirm some basic assumptions

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turned out that this was a strange (and frustrating) problem, which has apparently been fixed by itself just by restarting my computer.. Holy restart key!